# Displaying form values in bootstrap tags input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a select, input and a button, what i want is when i click on the button to get the values of the select and input, i managed to do that and they get displayed in an alert, my question is, how can i concatenate those two retrieved values and display them in one alert? and can i display them in bootstrap tags input instead of an alert? here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert($('input').val());
     alert($('select').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text">
<button type="button">Get values</button> 
</form>
```

in bootstrap input tag, how can i do that? here is my code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Check my changes to your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var str = 'Input value: ' + $('input').val() + ' select value: ' + $('select').val();
    // Alerting your values
    alert(str);
    // Writing them to html element
    $('#element').html(str);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text">
<button type="button">Get values</button> 
</form>
<span id="element"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the two values in the same alert do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var first = $('input').val();
    var second = $('select').val();
    alert(first + second);
  });
});
```

To get the "alert" to have the styles afforded by foundation you will have to something like https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html

Which is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You know how to grab the value from the input, and you know how to grab the value from the select.

All you need to do now is use javascript's .concat() method:

`const combinedValue = $('input').val().concat($('select').val());`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    const combinedValue = $('input').val().concat($('select').val());
    alert(combinedValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text">
<button type="button">Get values</button> 
</form>
```